# Infinite animation in RecyclerView stops after scrolling

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I have multityped `RecyclerView` with animated views(blinking white circles) inside items. During `recyclerView` scrolling animations can randomly stop working.

I thought this problem is connected with `onCreateViewHolder` or `onBindViewHolder`, but this issue reproducing even if none of this methods were called.

Animation repeat count set to infinite, `clearAnimation()` only called in `onBindViewHolder`.

My adapter code :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.annimon.stream.Stream;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

    private final int avatarSize;
    private List<IncomingTextMessage> chatMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    private User appOwner;
    private User wallOwner;
    private int MESSAGE_TYPE_MY = 0;
    private int MESSAGE_TYPE_INTERLOCUTOR = 1;
    private SimpleDateFormat timeFormat;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
    private static final String TAG = "ChatAdapter";

    private int bindViewHolderCallCounter = 0;


    public ChatAdapter(User appOwner, User wallOwner, Context context) {
        this.appOwner = appOwner;
        this.wallOwner = wallOwner;
        avatarSize = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.post_avatar_size);
        timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(context.getString(R.string.time_format));
        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(context.getString(R.string.server_date_parsing_format));
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));

        View v;
        if (viewType == MESSAGE_TYPE_MY) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_my_chat_message, parent, false);
            v.setBackgroundColor(color);
            return new MyMessageViewHolder(v);
        } else  {  //viewType == MESSAGE_TYPE_INTERLOCUTOR
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_interlocutor_chat_message, parent, false);
            v.setBackgroundColor(color);
            return new InterlocutorMessageViewHolder(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        bindViewHolderCallCounter++;



        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder:" + chatMessages.get(position).getText() + "   " + (getItemViewType(position) == MESSAGE_TYPE_MY));
        if (getItemViewType(position) == MESSAGE_TYPE_MY) {
            MyMessageViewHolder myMessageViewHolder = (MyMessageViewHolder) holder;
            setUserAvatar(appOwner, myMessageViewHolder.ivUserAvatar);
            myMessageViewHolder.ivUserAvatar.setTag(appOwner);
            myMessageViewHolder.ivUserAvatar.setOnClickListener(this);
            myMessageViewHolder.tvText.setText(chatMessages.get(position).getText() +" bindViewHolderCallCounter " + bindViewHolderCallCounter);
            myMessageViewHolder.tvTime.setText(formatTime(chatMessages.get(position).getDateTime()));

            setupMessageState(myMessageViewHolder, chatMessages.get(position));

        } else /*if (getItemViewType(position) == MESSAGE_TYPE_INTERLOCUTOR)*/ {
            InterlocutorMessageViewHolder interlocutorMessageViewHolder = (InterlocutorMessageViewHolder) holder;
            setUserAvatar(wallOwner, interlocutorMessageViewHolder.ivUserAvatar);
            interlocutorMessageViewHolder.ivUserAvatar.setTag(wallOwner);
            interlocutorMessageViewHolder.ivUserAvatar.setOnClickListener(this);
            interlocutorMessageViewHolder.tvText.setText(chatMessages.get(position).getText());
            interlocutorMessageViewHolder.tvTime.setText(formatTime(chatMessages.get(position).getDateTime()));

        }
    }

    private void setupMessageState(MyMessageViewHolder myMessageViewHolder, IncomingTextMessage message) {
        Log.d(TAG, "setupMessageState");

        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(myMessageViewHolder.ivUserAvatar.getContext(), R.anim.fade_out_in_chat_circle);

        myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingSending.clearAnimation();
        myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingReading.clearAnimation();
        myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingSending.clearAnimation();

        switch (message.getState()) {
            case MessageNotification.SENT: {
                Log.d(TAG, "MessageNotification.SENT" + message.getText());
                myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingSending.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingReading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingSending.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingSending.setAnimation(animation);
                break;
            }
            case MessageNotification.RECEIVED:
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "MessageNotification.RECEIVED" + message.getText());

                myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingSending.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingReading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingSending.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingReading.setAnimation(animation);
                break;
            }
            case MessageNotification.DELIEVERED:
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "MessageNotification.DELIEVERED" + message.getText());

                myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingSending.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingReading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingSending.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingReading.setAnimation(animation);
                break;
            }
            case MessageNotification.READ:
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "MessageNotification.READ" + message.getText());

                myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingSending.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingReading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingSending.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private String formatTime(String severDate) {
        try {
            dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

            return timeFormat.format(dateFormat.parse(severDate));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Time string parsing error :" + severDate);
            return "";
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (chatMessages.get(position).getAuthorId().equals(String.valueOf(appOwner.getId())))
            return MESSAGE_TYPE_MY;
        else return MESSAGE_TYPE_INTERLOCUTOR;
    }

    private void setUserAvatar(BaseUser user, ImageView imageView) {
        if (user != null && user.getPrimaryImageUrl() != null && !user.getPrimaryImageUrl().isEmpty()) {
            Picasso.with(imageView.getContext())
                    .load(user.getPrimaryImageUrl())
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_user_avatar_128)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .resize(avatarSize, avatarSize)
                    .transform(new RoundedTransformation())
                    .into(imageView);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_user_avatar_128);
        }
    }



 /*   public void addNewUsers(List<BaseUser> newUsers) {
        this.chatMessages = newUsers;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }*/

    public void addMessage(IncomingTextMessage incomingTextMessage) {
        this.chatMessages.add(incomingTextMessage);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void changeMessageState(MessageNotification notification) {
        Stream.of(chatMessages)
                .filter(message -> message.getId().equals(notification.getMessageId()))
                .forEach(message ->
                {
                    message.setState(notification.getState());
                    notifyItemChanged(chatMessages.indexOf(message));
                });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chatMessages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return chatMessages.get(position).getId().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getTag() instanceof User) {
            User user = (User) view.getTag();
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Config.USER_STRING_EXTRA, user.getId());
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public void addMessages(ArrayList<IncomingTextMessage> incomingTextMessages) {
        chatMessages.addAll(incomingTextMessages);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class MyMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.vMessageStatusAwaitingSending)
        View vMessageStatusAwaitingSending;

        @Bind(R.id.vMessageStatusAwaitingDelivering)
        View vMessageStatusAwaitingDelivering;

        @Bind(R.id.vMessageStatusAwaitingReading)
        View vMessageStatusAwaitingReading;

        @Bind(R.id.ivUserAvatar)
        ImageView ivUserAvatar;

        @Bind(R.id.tvText)
        TextView tvText;

        @Bind(R.id.tvTime)
        TextView tvTime;

        public MyMessageViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }

    class InterlocutorMessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.ivUserAvatar)
        ImageView ivUserAvatar;

        @Bind(R.id.tvText)
        TextView tvText;

        @Bind(R.id.tvTime)
        TextView tvTime;

        public InterlocutorMessageViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }
}
```

Blinking animation xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="650"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toAlpha="0.1" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I ran into the same issue and found that the animation stops when the view gets detached from the window. When it is reattached, you won't get the `onBindViewHolder` call so the animation won't start.

The solution is to override `onViewAttachedToWindow` in your `RecyclerView.Adapter<>` and call `setAnimation` from there. You'll also need to maintain a reference to the `IncomingTextMessage` in the `ViewHolder` because `onViewAttachedToWindow` doesn't pass in the position.

Example:

```
@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
  if (holder instanceof MyMessageViewHolder) {
    MyMessageViewHolder messageHolder = (MyMessageViewHolder)holder;
    setupMessageState(messageHolder, messageHolder.message); // messageHolder.message being the IncomingTextMessage kept in MyMessageViewHolder
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me too. However, can anyone explain why onBindViewHolder is not getting called when it is reattached?

Comment: @YasithaChinthaka I learned that if item is not changed theres no onBind called - the item doesnt need to be rebound - it is just fetched from cache. I learned it from https://youtu.be/LqBlYJTfLP4 or https://youtu.be/imsr8NrIAMs or https://youtu.be/KhLVD6iiZQs

Answer (score 0):

Try to set animation to null in your `MessageNotification.READ` case:

```
    case MessageNotification.READ:
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "MessageNotification.READ" + message.getText());

                    myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingSending.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingReading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingSending.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingReading.setAnimation(null);

                    break;
                }
```

Comment: I just tryed it with no success.Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: hm.. try also to replace `myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingSending.clearAnimation();` with  `myMessageViewHolder.vMessageStatusAwaitingReading.setAnimation(null);`

Comment: Actually, I did that too, I just dont mentioned about it.Also note that `onBindViewHolder` method is not even calling (i double checked that).That fact make things too complicated.